# SQlite: Find closest match (String) in a table with sentences and variations

Tags: java, algorithm, sqlite, match

I'm currently trying to figure out what the best SQL query would look like to find a row with a static sentence(text) based on a dynamic sentence with multiple variations. 
Here is an example:

```
tbl_questions:

iQuestionID, sQuestion
1, "how was your day"
2, "what is your name"
3, "how old are you"
```

so the search string

```
"what name do you have"
```

should return the second row.
or

```
"so, tell me how old you are"
```

should return the third row.

Is a SQL query similar to this problem possible without complex search algorithms on code base?

Comment: This is not an appropriate operation for SQL.

Comment: Are you sure? I think breaking up the sentence into words and use some operations will solve this problem, but I don't know how to do this in SQL.

Comment: A SQL query similar to this problem is not possible.

Comment: @Noneatme . . . You'll need a parsing function to break it into words.  You might find Levenshtein distance helpful.  In all likelihood, you will need to implement your own functions for this.  In my opinion, you should do the work in Java, Python, or some other language like that.

Comment: But this might cause a issue with more than 2 million data sets so I really like to do the work in SQL :/
Anyway, thanks for your help